# DRUPAL : change the value of taxonomy with customfields PHP

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to know if it's possible to change, with Customfields PHP, the value that I get from taxonomy. I need this because I want to upload the file in amazon but the amazon template doesn't recognizes any names. For example if I want to upload a T-Shirt, in my website the name is Shirts, but Amazon recognize just Shirt. So when I get the value with taxonomy I want to change with Customfields PHP the name Shirts in Shirt.

I tried to search the variable in the query but about taxonomy there isn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the taxonomy term names from the configuration pages. See more in the [Drupal.org documentation for Taxonomy](https://drupal.org/node/774892).

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).